# HSL with videoJS not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have a m3u8 stream provided by Plex Media Server, and when i look on chrome or FF it works great, but when going to the page on IE9 it says:
`The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.`

this is the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="http://ip:port/video/:/transcode/universal/start?path=http%3A%2F%2Fip%3Aport%2Flibrary%2Fmetadata%2F1&fastSeek=1&X-Plex-Platform=Internet+Explorer&offset=0" type='video/mp4' />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding the following plugin: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls

but no luck there.
Anybody got any clue what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [readme](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls#documentation), videojs-contrib-hls does not support Internet Explorer < 10 unfortunately. I don't have the exact details, but it's because the tech requires more advanced and better performing javascript than is available on IE9.

btw, in your code the mime type is 'video/mp4'.

Comment: yea, was thinking it  would come down to that. oh well i'll figure something out